# How to configure stylelint for react native and StyleSheet

Tags: react-native, config, stylelint

Does anyone know how to configure stylelint for react native (typescript) and StyleSheet?

**src/sample.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>React Native</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea"
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: "#20232a",
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#61dafb",
    color: "#20232a",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  example: {
    unknown: "property"
  }
});

export default App;
```

**.stylelintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "plugins": ["stylelint-react-native"],
  "rules": {
    "react-native/css-property-no-unknown": true
  }
}
```

When I run *stylelint '/src/**/*.tsx'*, I got error like "you need use postcss". Ok, I found this *@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js* package, but no matter how I connect it, nothing works.

In the best case, the command runs without errors, although I added a property of which does not exist.

PS. stylelint version - 14, react native version - 0.66.4

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js` custom syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js).

**test.ts**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>React Native</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    color: "#eaeae",
    background: "linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5)",
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});

export default App;
```

**.stylelintrc.json**  (with three example rules turned on)

```
{
  "customSyntax": "@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js",
  "rules": {
    "color-no-invalid-hex": true,
    "font-weight-notation": "numeric",
    "function-disallowed-list": ["linear-gradient"]
  }
}
```

**output**

```
% npx stylelint "test.ts"

test.ts
 12:12  ✖  Unexpected invalid hex color "#eaeae"  color-no-invalid-hex    
 13:17  ✖  Unexpected function "linear-gradient"  function-disallowed-list
 16:17  ✖  Expected numeric font-weight notation  font-weight-notation
```

You may want to use both Stylelint and the [eslint-plugin-react-native](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native) plugin for ESLint together as they are complementary tools that do different things.

The ESLint plugin has [7 rules](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native#list-of-supported-rules). Only one of which, [`sort-styles`](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native/blob/master/docs/rules/sort-styles.md), overlaps with Stylelint. The other rules don't touch on the actual CSS inside your object notation. So you can use that plugin and then use Stylelint to [spot possible errors](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list#possible-errors) and [limit what language features are used](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list#limit-language-features) in your CSS.

---

> I found this @stylelint/postcss-css-in-js package, but no matter how I connect it, nothing works

You may have encountered a bug in the package. It is a monolithic package that tries to support every flavour of CSS-in-JS. It'll likely be deprecated in the future in favour of leaner packages dedicated to specific CSS-in-JS libraries, the first of which is [postcss-lit](https://github.com/43081j/postcss-lit).